# Check if date range fall within a WW

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question about comparing date ranges.
I have a table that hold a state log of a machine. The state can be 0 or 1. In addition I have the date when the machine state change started and when it ended

```
START_DATE | END_DATE | STATE
```

For example:

```
     START_DATE     |       END_DATE        | STATE
2019-05-28 07:12:43   2019-05-29 09:12:43       1
2019-05-29 09:12:43   2019-06-01 08:12:43       0
2019-06-11 10:12:43   2019-06-12 16:12:43       1
2019-06-12 16:12:43   2019-06-12 17:12:43       0
```

I want to make a report that iterate through each WW (work week) and check what average state was on that WW.

My problem is that a state change could have happened on WW22 and ended on WW24 so when I GROUP BY WW I get no values on WW23 because there was no start or end state on WW23. But on WW23 that machine was on state 0 because it started on WW22 and ended on WW24 but through all the this time the state was 0.

It seems that I cant use GROUP BY WW to solve it. 
I may need to check START_DATE and END_DATE on cases there is no records on WW23. to add something like:

```
CASE WHEN WW BETWEEN START_DATE AND END_DATE THEN...
```

But im not sure how to loop on the WW without using GROUP BY.

I use SQL ORACLE

Thanks.

Comment: What is a "WW"?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: WW = work week, I updated the question.
Example inside, thanks.

Comment: The typical way to handle date-based reporting is to create a Calendar table with dates for the next eg 20 years and precalculated columns for the year, month, quarter, week number (ISO or not), vacations, reporting periods etc. You can join the data with the Calendar table and group eg by Year and WeekNumber to get the aggregates you want

Comment: Hi, thanks for you comment. I canot join with the Calendar table because I have no record on some dates because there was no change on this dates but still the machine have some state which stated a long time before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood correctly. It would be good if You showed us your query and tell us how you count average state and where these weeks come from. Anyway here is query which generates all weeks for year 2019 and joins with your `log`.

```
select to_char(wsd, 'iw') week, wsd, start_date, end_date, state
  from (
    select trunc(date '2019-01-01', 'iw') + level * 7 - 7 wsd
      from dual 
      connect by trunc(date '2019-01-01', 'iw') + level * 7 <= date '2020-01-01')
  left join log on wsd < end_date and start_date < wsd + 7
```

Interesting is this range:

```
week  week_start_date  log_start            log_end              state
21    2019-05-20
22    2019-05-27       2019-05-28 07:12:43  2019-05-29 09:12:43  1
22    2019-05-27       2019-05-29 09:12:43  2019-06-01 08:12:43  0
23    2019-06-03
24    2019-06-10       2019-06-11 10:12:43  2019-06-12 16:12:43  1
24    2019-06-10       2019-06-12 16:12:43  2019-06-12 17:12:43  0
25    2019-06-17
```

I don't know how you count average state for weeks 22 and 24. Maybe it is weighted average of substracted times, maybe somehow other. But it's not important, now you have row for week 23, with missing `state`. 
If this means that previous value is valid for this week use:

```
nvl(state, lag(state) over (order by wsd))
```

or

```
coalesce(state, lag(state) over (order by wsd), 0)
```

when you want `0` as default value when we also miss previous week(s). If two weeks are missing add `ignore nulls` to `lag`.

Then you can group data by weeks and count average values.

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b496adc0413da8314425ac57a4aa7d52)</sup>**

Comment: Assuming work week starts on Sunday, I'd think you'd want to start from 2018-12-30.